# JSTL forEach do not work. Used in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl, jsp-tags

i have a problem with the forEach-tag from JSTL in my Spring MVC Application.

I want to iterate over a simple LinkedList with objects. Here you can see my code from the .jsp file:

```
    <c:forEach items="${posts}" var="single_post">
        <div id="post">
            <label><c:out value="${single_post.topic}" /></label> <br />
            <div id="post_content">
                <c:out value="${single_post.content}" />
            </div>
            <div id="post_information">
                <c:out value="${single_post.username}" />
                |
                <c:out value="${single_post.dayOfCreation}" />
            </div>
            <div id="post_tags">
                <c:out value="${single_post.tags}" />
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
```

The forEach-tag iterates over the complete list, but returns only the first element.
I tried it on an other case with a simple example, but without a LinkedList.

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5">
    Item <c:out value="${i}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

This example works fine, so i don't know where the problem is.

Best regards :)

**Update 1:** 
The code which generates the list is a simple sql statement. The results of the statement are added to the LinkedList.

In my controller, i have the following method to add the results of the sql statement to the model:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/community", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String community(Locale locale, Model model) {

    // Add attributes to the model
    model.addAttribute("posts", appService.getRelatedPosts());

    return "/community";
}
```

The result of the forEach-tag looks like this:

Test Titel 
Beispieltext 
TestAccount | Tag_1, Tag2, Tag_3 
Test Titel
Beispieltext 
TestAccount | Tag_1, Tag2, Tag_3 
Test Titel
Beispieltext 
TestAccount | Tag_1, Tag2, Tag_3 
. 
. 
.

And yes, there are different values in the database ;)

Comment: Did you confirm the size of the list before placing it inside the Model?

Comment: This looks right. Are you sure `${posts}` contains more than one value?

Comment: yes i'm sure that the list contains more elemts. I checked it before the .jsp file is loading.
The forEach-loop iterates over several times on the list, but it returns only the first object.

Comment: Show us the code which populates the list and stores it in the request. Show us the generated HTML code. And side note: this generated HTML is invalid. An ID should be unique. This code will generate N elements with the same ID.

Comment: Thanks JB, i fixed the id's by changing them to classes. I added an update to my post, with the controller code and the screen output of the code.

Comment: Then you have a bug in `appService.getRelatedPosts()`. You're probably adding the same object repeatedly into the list instead of creating a new object at each iteration.

Comment: Oh thanks alot! That was my problem. I fixed it  and now it works! :)